# Canvas Of HTML5 While Using Phonegap Too Slow On Android

Tags: android, html, performance, canvas, cordova

Using a Galaxy S4 (Android 4.3) to run a Phonegap 3.4 app which has a HTML5's canvas running animations.

When I run the app normally, it works fine with 'ok' FPS while drawing stuff on the canvas..

When I want to turn the app to be using the max possible screen resolution of the smart-phone, adding the code below:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //... some code
    appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    //... more code
}
```

Than yes the screen resolution is OK, but the animations move at around 1 FPS.. which is very bad.

How can I improve performance ?
Am I getting to the max screen resolution (code I posted) doing the right way ?

Comment: This may be a long shot, but I have had trouble with it in the past, in `AndroidManifest.xml` look for the `debuggable` value and set it to `false` and also try toggling `hardwareAccelerated` between `true` and `false`. These seem to affect performance in various configurations.

Comment: Hey, Can't find a 'debuggable' value in my AndroidManifest.xml, Are you sure it should be there, or maybe somewhere else ?

Comment: you can add it to the `application` node like this: `<application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">`

Comment: Changing HardwareAccelerated to true or false doesn't change anything

Comment: Nor did adding android:debuggable="true" or android:debuggable="false" changed anything

Answer (score 1):

If your app is full screen, you can try [the Adobe FastCanvas plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas) instead of the regular Canvas, it should be much faster.

Comment: Hello, it says it's built for Android, what should be done when running the app on iOS ?

Comment: I mentionned this plugin because your question was about android. I don't know about IOS, but I'm not sure this plugin is needed for IOS, it was built because canvas in android webview are very slow.

Comment: When I try to install it using PLugman, it asks for user/passowrd in the console, why is that ?
( plugman install --platform android --project <your project folder> --plugin https://github.com/FastCanvas/FastCanvas.git )